# AppDelegate callback for root view loaded

Tags: ios, swift

My app includes an update screen that fetches new data from our API. This is currently invoked manually from the slide in menu.

I want to add in an "update detected" feature on app load. So that when the app loads, it checks for new data, and if there is new data it shows the update screen as a `popover`. I also want to show the update screen on the first app load (as we ship the app with no data - so it needs to run the update at least one before using it)

The app is very simple and the `root view controller` is currently a `navcontroller` which has 3 or 4 VC's in series (thats pretty much the entire app apart from the side menu that opens a couple of info pages and the update screen).

I figure what I need to do is run the "update check" in the `AppDelegate`, and if it returns true, present the popover. However I get this error:

> 2016-11-01 13:02:28.507 XXX[38895:1026306] Warning: Attempt to present
>    on
>     whose view is not in
>   the window hierarchy!

Which is I guess because the `root controller` hasn't been loaded and presented yet.

Whats the best way too fix this. I have a couple of idea's but not sure if any are good or not, or even if they will work!

1. Try to find some sort of "root view controller is loaded" callback
   to use in app delegate
2. Put the update check into my initial view controller (but this isn't where it belongs, I should be able to change the initial view controller without it affecting the update check as they are seperate things)
3. Some sort of "router view" as my initial view controller that I can put the logic into for the check. However I don't want this screen to hold up the app (i.e. I dont want a spinner on there making the user wait for the update check - I want them to go straight into using the app and the update popover shows if needed)

Any advice on this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you should create new UIViewController (CheckForUpdateViewController)
and set that view controller as a root view controller. Then instead of checking for update within AppDelegate, you can add that check within CheckForUpdateViewController.m. There you will be able to present popover if needed or to open navigation view controller if there is no update available.

Comment: I'd considered this but i didn't want the update to block getting into the app until it's done it's check. The update check needs to be run asynchronously in the background and popover shown if needed. I don't think your approach would allow this, but thankyour for the reply

Comment: Whati forgot to mention is that i'm not currently doing the check (hardcoded to true for dev purposes). If i delay the present action by 0.1 seconds in an NSTimer, then it works.

Comment: If you set root view within AppDelegate, then you should add check for update within root view controller. So in your case you will have navigationController as a root view, and within viewDidLoad() of that navigation controller you can check if there is an update or not and based on that information show popover or not.

Answer (score 0):

try to push that loading indicator on the window than the root view controller. or select the first VC and put it on it.

Comment: I can't put it on the window as that would mean setting it as the root view controller (which i don't want, i want the main nav controler to be root and the update screen to be modally presented).

I have tried putting it onto the first VC (i think, i'm getting the root VC and using that), but that causes the error above